# C# - Why can't I pass a class declared in a using statement as a reference type?

Tags: c#

Suppose I have the following disposable class and example code to run it:

```
public class DisposableInt : IDisposable
{
    private int? _Value;

    public int? MyInt
    {
        get { return _Value; }
        set { _Value = value; }
    }

    public DisposableInt(int InitialValue)
    {
        _Value = InitialValue;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _Value = null;
    }
}

public class TestAnInt
{
    private void AddOne(ref DisposableInt IntVal)
    {
        IntVal.MyInt++;
    }

    public void TestIt()
    {
        DisposableInt TheInt;
        using (TheInt = new DisposableInt(1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Int Value: {0}", TheInt.MyInt));
            AddOne(ref TheInt);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Int Value + 1: {0}", TheInt.MyInt));
        }
    }
}
```

Calling `new TestAnInt().TestIt()` runs just fine.  However, if I change `TestIt()` so that `DisposableInt` is declared inside of the using statement like so:

```
    public void TestIt()
    {
        // DisposableInt TheInt;
        using (DisposableInt TheInt = new DisposableInt(1))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Int Value: {0}", TheInt.MyInt));
            AddOne(ref TheInt);
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Int Value + 1: {0}", TheInt.MyInt));
        }
    }
```

I get the following compiler error:

```
Cannot pass 'TheInt' as a ref or out argument because it is a 'using variable'
```

Why is this?  What is different, other than the class goes out of scope and to the garbage collector once the `using` statement is finished?

(and yeah, I know my disposable class example is quite silly, I'm just trying to keep matters simple)

Comment: Just a tip: conventionally, Java variables are named with the first letter lower-case and camelCased on word boundaries. Your `TheInt` variable should be renamed `theInt`. It helps the readability of your code to others if you follow conventions.

Comment: Your example code doesn't even need ref at all, since you are not trying to change the reference.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

> Why is this?

Variables *declared* in `using` statements are read-only; `out` and `ref` parameters aren't. So you *can* do this:

```
DisposableInt theInt = new DisposableInt(1);
using (theInt)
{
    AddOne(ref theInt);
}
```

... but fundamentally you're not *using* the fact that it's a `ref` parameter anyway...

It's possible that you've misunderstood what `ref` really means. It would be a good idea to read my [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) to make sure you really understand.

Comment: Thank you!  The missing link for me was that a 'using variable' is read-only.  I think I see why:  Because then I could say theInt = new DisposableInt(2) *inside* the using statement mucking things up royally!  So even my "working" sample code is bad practice, I guess.