# How to pass a struct as a ref in a using clause?

Tags: c#, struct, ref

Here's what I want to do:

```
using(var bmp = Surface.FromBmp("smile.bmp"))
{
    tex = Texture.FromSurface(ref rend, ref bmp);
}
```

`Surface` is a `struct`. I want to avoid making a copy of the struct just to pass it to `Texture.FromSurface`, so I'm passing it as a `ref` even though it's not modified. C# doesn't have a concept of const-refs, so I'm not sure what else I can do. Are there any elegant solutions?

I found [Jon Skeet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11636545/65387), but it doesn't really offer a solution.

Comment: Are you sure that copying the Surface is actually bad? I can't believe that they build a struct to hold a complete surface, the Surface struct probably only holds something like a SurfaceHandle anyway.

Comment: @nvoigt: You're right..it's not as bad as I thought. It's about 6 ints, 4 pointers, ... and another struct with another 4 ints... I estimate it's about 60 bytes. It's coming from C though, I think some of the other guys are even bigger.

Comment: Standard .NET guidance is that a struct should not be larger than 16 bytes and have more than 4 fields.  If you go past that then a struct stops being useful as a value type and should be replaced by a class.  Using *ref* here is a C practice, it just isn't very appropriate in C#.

Comment: `bmp` is necessarily a struct as it does come from C, although based on the answers I'm seeing here it seems like it might be better to wrap it in a class and drop the refs.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the same code `using` is [using (`try`/`finally`)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx) by hand. Something like:

```
IDisposable toClose = null;
try 
{
    var bmp = Surface.FromBmp("smile.bmp"));
    toClose = bmp;
    tex = Texture.FromSurface(ref rend, ref bmp);
}
finally 
{
    toClose.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The only type whose "struct-ness" would be a problem is that of `bmp`; are you saying that is a struct?  If so, it would seem highly unusual that a struct would implement a non-trivial `IDisposable.Dispose()` method, but it's possible that the type is implemented as an "immutable" struct but encapsulates a mutable reference and behaves like one.  In that case, I would suggest something like:

```
var bmp = Surface.FromBmp("smile.bmp");
try
{
  tex = Texture.FromSurface(ref rend, ref bmp);
}
bmp.Dispose(); // Or whatever method it exposes for such purpose
```

If the type in question actually requires disposal, it should expose a method for such purpose (some structure types like `List<T>.Enumerator` implement `IDisposable` because they are required to implement the interface, not because instances require cleanup).  Do not cast to `IDisposable`, since that will create a new boxed instance of the structure; the cost of that will significantly exceed the cost of creating another struct instance.  Another pattern you might be able to use would be:

```
var bmp = Surface.FromBmp("smile.bmp");
using(bmp)
{
  tex = Texture.FromSurface(ref rend, ref bmp);
}
```

since I think that form of the `using` statement creates its own private copy of its argument and will let you do what you like with the original, but there's no real reason why it should be necessary to have code make the extra copy of `bmp`, so I wouldn't particularly recommend that form.  If for whatever reason `bmp` requires cleanup but does not expose any method for that purpose other than via `IDisposable`, you could do something like:

```
void CallDisposeOnRef<T>(ref T it) where T:IDisposable { it.Dispose(); }
```

and replace the last line of my first example with `CallDisposeOnRef(ref bmp);`, which would avoid having to make an extra copy of `bmp` in any fashion (the name is verbose to make clear that it *only* calls `Dispose` on the target; some people might expect such a method that takes a `ref` parameter to also set its argument to `null`)

Comment: I'm writing a wrapper around SDL, the dispose method simple calls [SDL_FreeSurface](http://sdl.beuc.net/sdl.wiki/SDL_FreeSurface). I thought it might be nice to have this in a disposable interface so that you can do things like I posted; load the BMP and then copy it into a texture and have it automatically cleaned up for you. While your solutions work, I don't think they make for a very nice API. I'm thinking it might be better to wrap the Surface struct in a class instead of exposing it directly.

Comment: @Mark: It's too bad some of the people involved in C# seem to fundamentally dislike structure types, and thus would rather say they shouldn't be used because of weaknesses in how they're handled, than fix those weaknesses.  Depending upon how often they're created and recycled, it sounds as though it may be appropriate for your type to be a structure, and you sound like you have the instincts necessary to use structures appropriately.

Comment: @Mark: Immutable classes add GC pressure, which would limit use of your code to situations where long-lived objects are seldom modified to hold references to recently-generated ones (Gen0 collections are usually cheap, but the existence of many references from long-lived objects into shorter ones can significantly increase their cost).  Mutable classes often have dodgy semantics.  Using a struct may be appropriate, if you can deal with the quirks in C#'s handling of them.